# How can I automatically add files to a Visual Studio solution that were made by another application

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I created a simple standalone SQL-table-to-class generator as a WPF application.

When I save files (e.g. a .cs class file) from that application into the directory structure of a separate web application I'm working on, it is of course not added to the solution.  I have to manually add it in.

Is there a way I can automatically tag it/flag it or whatever, to be included in the web application solution?

Comment: Right click in Project and Add existing item perhaps?

Comment: I'm considering that "manual" labor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I know of is to manually modify the .proj file and add a content include directive for the directories you want with a wildcard.

```
<Content Include="SomeDirectory\*" />
```

You will need to do this for each directory and it isn't recursive.  The major down-side though, is that you must reload the project for it to pick up new files.

Personally, I consider this to be a bit of hack and would never use it in a serious project.

Comment: I agree with your hack sentiment.  Since I'm using my custom tool only at dev time, manually adding the files hasn't been too much of a problem.  I guess I was worried that I would need to "re-include" the file every time I created the file externally, which of course is not the case.